# Set the value for input label in laravel 5 form

Tags: laravel-5

This is the code where I need to set the value for the label :

```
{!! Form::label('unit',$value=$fileN) !!}
```

When I coded that it will display the following error.

> ErrorException in UploadController.php line 51:
>   Undefined index: unit

I changed that to {{ Form::label('unit', $fileN) }}. But above same error will display. Below is the output.

```
<label for="unit">rainforest.pdf</label>
```

Controller method look likes below.

```
public function edit1()
{

    $grade = $_POST['grade'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $unit = $_POST['unit'];
    $uplds = Upldtbl::findOrFail($id);


    DB::table('upldtbls')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(['title' => $title, 'subject' => $subject,'url' => $unit, 'grade' => $grade]);


    return redirect('/hgh');
}


{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'hgh1','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true, 'class'=>'upldform')) !!}
                                    <table>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                              <div class="controls">
                                                  <tr>

                                                         <td> <b>{!! Form::label('Grade', 'Grade') !!}</b></td>

                                                         <td> {!! Form::select('grade', array('Grade' => 'Grade','2' => '2', '3' => '3','4' => '4'), $value=$grade) !!}</td>

                                                   </tr>
                                                   @if(Session::has('errorUpldGrade'))
                                                      <tr>
                                                          <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px">{!! Session::get('errorUpldGrade') !!}</ul></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   @endif

                                                   <tr>

                                                       <td><b>{!! Form::label('Subject', 'Subject') !!}</b></td>
                                                       <td>{!! Form::select('subject', array('Subject' => 'Subject','English' => 'English', 'Mathematics' => 'Mathematics','Environmental Studies' => 'Environmental Studies'), $value=$sub) !!}</td>
                                                   </tr>
                                                   @if(Session::has('errorUpldSubj'))
                                                      <tr>
                                                          <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"><p class="errors">{!! Session::get('errorUpldSubj') !!}</p></ul></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   @endif

                                                   <tr>
                                                       <td> <b>{!! Form::label('Title', 'Title') !!}</b></td>
                                                       <td>  {!! Form::text('title',$value=$title) !!}</td>
                                                   </tr>


                                                   @if(Session::has('errorUpldTitle'))
                                                      <tr>
                                                          <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"><p class="errors">{!! Session::get('errorUpldTitle') !!}</p></ul></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   @endif

                                                      <tr>

                                                          <td>{!! Form::file('image') !!}{{ Form::label('unit', $fileN) }}</td>
                                                          <td><p class="errors">{!!$errors->first('image')!!}</p></td>

                                                      </tr>
                                                     @if(Session::has('errorUpldFile'))
                                                      <tr>

                                                      <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"><p class="errors">{!! Session::get('errorUpldFile') !!}</p></ul></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                     @endif
                                                     <td>{!! Form::hidden('id',$id ) !!}</td><br>
                                              </div>
                                         </div>


                                        <tr>
                                            <td> {!! Form::submit('Update', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}</td>


                                        </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Can anybody help me that out?

Comment: Show the controller.

Comment: I have updated with controller method above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong declaration of label, instead of :

```
{!! Form::label('unit',$value=$fileN) !!}
```

It should be :

```
{{ Form::label('unit', $fileN) }}
```

And you're getting the error `Undefined index: unit` because you don't have any field with name `unit` and you're trying to capture it in :

```
 $unit = $_POST['unit'];
```

You could use hidden field to send value of unit like :

```
{!! Form::hidden('unit',$fileN) !!}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then it will dispaly this and the same previous error.   <label for="unit">rainforest.pdf</label>

Comment: Do you get this error after clicking on submit button? and please show us the 51 line.

Comment: That means your problem is not a label try to add the full form to the your question.

Comment: I have added the form after the controller method.

Comment: Yes and that make sens now, you're getting the error because you don't have any field with name `unit` and you're trying to capture it in `$unit = $_POST['unit'];`.

Comment: There label field is named as unit. Did you see that?

Comment: I mean by `field` (input,select) and not label of field, since submit will send just fields and not labels.

Comment: Thank you. Then how should I get the value from a label. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I need to display the label. So I have to add an extra label. Thank you.